# Web Responsive - Convert Table Header

Tags: html, css

I have this table

```
    <table border="1">

<thead><tr>
    <th>Index</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>Change</th>
    <th>Change %</th>
    <th>Year High</th>
    <th>Year Low</th>
    <th>Daily Low</th>
    <th>Daily High</th>
    <th>Turnover €(Mil.)</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>ABC® Overall</td>
    <td>2,725.99</td>
    <td>-15.30</td>
    <td>-0.56%</td>
     <td>3,037.89</td>
     <td>2,333.35</td>
     <td>2,712.84</td>
     <td>2,743.31</td>
    <td>24.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>ABC® Financial</td>
    <td>130.77</td>
    <td>-3.24</td>
    <td>-2.42%</td>
    <td>493.83</td>
    <td>101.54</td>
    <td>130.43</td>
    <td>136.14</td>
    <td>2.76</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>ABC® General</td>
    <td>3,751.79</td>
    <td>-17.49</td>
    <td>-0.46%</td>
    <td>4,146.84</td>
    <td>3,188.68</td>
    <td>3,731.15</td>
    <td>3,770.88</td>
    <td>21.24</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>ABC® Small Cap.</td>
    <td>1,661.94</td>
    <td>3.76</td>
    <td>0.23%</td>
    <td>2,175.60</td>
    <td>1,633.21</td>
    <td>1,643.92</td>
    <td>1,661.94</td>
    <td>0.20</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

When the browser gets smaller, as expected, the table's header turns to vertcal and `tbody` turns, too.  But when the browser gets much smaller, the whole `tbody`is break down and each `<tr>...</tr>` is break down, too.

How can I get `tbody` and each `<tr>...</tr>` stay when the browser gets smaller?

Also, in CSS I try to set up a navigator bar for `tbody` when the browser gets smaller, but it doesn't work!  Any idea?

CSS

```
table{
     display:block;
     padding: 0px;
     position:relative;
     border-spacing:0;
     margin-top: 0px;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     margin-left: auto;
}

thead{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear:both;
    background-color:#3399ff;

}
tbody{

    white-space:nowrap;
     display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;


}
tbody tr {
    float:left;
    min-width:auto;
    text-wrap:yes;
    display:inline-block
}
th, td{
   display:block;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 0px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2R877/)

Answer (score 1):

Consider reworking with DIVs. Tables and responsive design is not a good mix.

Comment: Thank you!  It is a positive way doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'd be able to achieve what you are trying to do without giving a fix width to the tbody and overriding styles for specific viewports.  Also consider a responsive table solution such as [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables) or [zurb](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tables.html) for responsive design. Saves you a lot of hassle in the long run.

```
tbody{

    white-space:nowrap;
     display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    position: relative;
    width:500px; /*Change this according to the requirements for specific viewports */

}
```

[UPDATED JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2R877/1/)

Comment: Thank you, Chan! Yes, I have tried to get some specific PX on the tbody's width, but it is still break down.  Do you have Bootstrap's Table's reference?  I search, but didn't see one, but I saw this [link](http://dbushell.com/demos/tables/rt_05-01-12.html).  It looks like what I expected, but somehow, I don't understand what they set CSS up.

Comment: The bootstrap reference is on the link. You can click it!

Comment: @abcidd. Do you mind accepting this answer. if this was what you were looking for?  Simply click the 'tick' next to the Answer on left?